# Is it possible to solve ambiguous by annotations in Java

Tags: java, annotations, ambiguous

I have two methods that in some cases have ambiguous call.
For example:

```
void bla(Integer a);
void bla(String a);
```

Basically when I call bla(null) I will get ambiguous call error.
Is it possible to write or use some annotation that will solve this issue before the compiler phase?

Can I block a null option from in `bla(String a)` before the compiler kicks in? I tried to wrote a NotNull annotation (but it kicks in after the compile phase).

See code below:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
public @interface NotNull1 {
    String value() default "";
}

void bla(@NotNull1 String a);
```

Answer (score 8):

Cast null to the type of the parameter of the method.

```
bla((Integer) null);
bla((String) null);
```

Comment: Yes I know that solution :) 
Since I'm writing an SDK I have no control on the casting phase.
I would like to disable the possibility of entering a null to the void bla(String a) method without the user getting ambiguous error in the process.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you are doing? I don't know how this can happen without you explicitly calling it with `null`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote an example in the main question.

Comment: I meant you how called it.

Comment: My project is available inside a JAR file so I test features in another java project by importing the JAR.

Comment: Yes, but I meant the syntax how you call this method. I don't see how you can create that error without explicitly doing `bla(null)`.

Comment: I'm doing it in my test project. :)
I added a new method with the same name and tested what will happen if i will call a method with null.